# Initial value space for Random Forest hyperparameter tuning

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search

I'm building a Random Forest Classifier using Scikit Learn.

My problem consists in a 4 class classification task, the values are distributed as follows (after splitting my data in training set and test set with a proportion of 80%-20%):

```
y_train values
cautious_turn       386  # label and number of elements
aggressive_brake    356
cautious_brake      245
aggressive_turn     204    

y_test values
cautious_turn       104
aggressive_brake     90
aggressive_turn      53
cautious_brake       51
```

The full dataset consists in 1489 samples. The training set is composed by 1191 samples.

I'm trying to optimize my random forest hyperparameters, using `RandomizedSearchCV` from `sklearn`.

My code is the following (just an example):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

# Number of trees in random forest
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 150, num = 15)]
# Number of features to consider at every split
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)
# Minimum number of samples required to split a node
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
# Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
# Method of selecting samples for training each tree
bootstrap = [True, False]
# Create the random grid
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}
```

So far, my code works perfectly and I have no problem.

**My question is:**
is there any way/empirical approach to decide which could be a possible good initial space for my hyperparameters values?

Right now I just copied those values from a tutorial. Is there any way to decide which could be (for example) a good range of values for `min_samples_split` looking at my data? Is there any methodology that allows me to reduce the "exploratory" space?

**For example** : I decided to search `min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]` instead of `min_samples_leaf = [10, 15, 20]` because.... (possible motivation here)